# Is it possible to change a route given by Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, customization

I'm writing a Google Maps mashup. I ask google the path from one location to another location. Google Maps gives me a Map with the route. I would like to take this route somehow and modify it (adding or removing points) before displaying it in the map. Is it possible? How would you do that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Google Maps API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections), there is a loadFromWaypoints function which will take waypoints in an Array and use them to calculate directions.

Edit: +1 for Cannonade.  What he said.

Comment: +1.  Maybe clarify you can mix address to be geocoded with latitude/longitudes in the supplied array?